# HMAC a php byte array

Tags: java, php, encoding, arrays, hmac

I'm trying to integrate a PHP backend with a Java backend. The Java backend expects some credentials which must be correctly encoded and hashed to match at both ends.

The java system converts a string to a sequence of bytes (1), then generates a HMAC/SHA256 keyed hash of that sequence (2) and then base 64 encodes the hash (3).

```
private static final String HMAC_ALGORITHM = "HmacSHA256";
final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec('mysecret', HMAC_ALGORITHM);
final Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
hmac.init(key);
final String stringToHash = "blablabla";
final byte[] bytesToHash = stringToHash.getBytes("UTF8");
final byte[] hash = hmac.doFinal(bytesToHash);
return Base64.encodeBytes(hash);
```

I can do (1) and convert the string in PHP to a sequence of bytes using

```
$stringArray = unpack('C*', $string);
```

// which works and is exactly the same as the Java system at this point

however the second part (2) doesn't seem to match, is there a way to pass a byte array to hmac in PHP because in Java the HMAC method accepts a byte array whereas the PHP one expects a string e.g.

```
hash_hmac('sha256', $stringArray, $secret);
```

or do I need to loop through the array and do some magic?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sam, facing the same issue. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 3):

I dont think you need to `unpack` in php

Just try

```
hash_hmac('sha256', $string, $secret, TRUE);
```

**Note:** I am passing the actual string to the function and the last param `raw_output` is set to `TRUE`

**Update**

Your java code seems to be wrong [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec.html)

```
final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec('mysecret', HMAC_ALGORITHM);
```

This should be like the following

```
byte[] keyBytes = mysecret.getBytes(); // say mysecret is a String var
final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, HMAC_ALGORITHM);
```

Comment: no joy unfortunately, the results differ between php and java

Comment: Java : private static final String HMAC_ALGORITHM = "HmacSHA256";
final String stringToHash = "blablabla";
final byte[] bytesToHash = stringToHash.getBytes("UTF8");
final byte[] hash = hmac.doFinal(bytesToHash);
return Base64.encodeBytes(hash);

Comment: I'm trying to write the PHP equivalent

Comment: Is that the full code can you add it to you question the the complete java code.

Comment: its the main bits, hopefully its all you need ?

Comment: Those things doesnt make sense. Thats why I asked for the full code.

Comment: that doesn't matter because I'm more interested in replicating it in PHP, the Java is just an example of what I need to achieve and is written and maintained by someone else

Comment: No it matters. If both parties doesnt use the standard way of create the signature how can you get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I have to generate the same Java values on PHP. The only way that it works was this

```
<?php

$verb = hash_hmac("sha256", "POST" , "9mO6oBVSmb2QTSeN73mEGHHnD", FALSE);

$path = hash_hmac("sha256", '/1.0/benefits/registerBenefit', pack("H*",  $verb), FALSE);

$query = hash_hmac("sha256", "" , pack("H*",  $path), FALSE);

$body  = hash_hmac("sha256", '{"id":"a7d23226-bdfc-4d85-a30a-b2d7eccc36e6","phone_number":"5511973512530","sku":"com.movile.cubes.br.biweekly.homolog","origin":"trade_up_group","application_id":437}' , pack("H*",  $query), FALSE);

$rawSignature   = hash_hmac("sha256", "x-kiwi-signature", pack("H*",  $body), FALSE);

$signature  = base64_encode( pack("H*",  $rawSignature));

var_dump($signature);
```

So..I had to use pack("H*", $str) to get the same values that Java was generating.